# What is the default Username and Password for ElasticSearch 7.2.0 (when x-pack enabled)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I did the change in `config/elasticsearch.yml` to

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

And now after starting elasticsearch (`./bin/elasticsearch`) and then do:
`curl localhost:9200`

getting:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}
```

Then tried these 2:

```
curl localhost:9200 -u elastic:elastic
curl localhost:9200 -u elastic:changeme
```

getting:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"failed to authenticate user [elastic]",
"header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}], "type":"security_exception", "reason":"failed to authenticate user [elastic]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}%
```

What is the default username/password for Elasticsearch 7.2.0?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `elasticsearch-setup-passwords` util to generate/set password for the inbuilt user of elastic.

To setup password you can use either one of the following commands:

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive

bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

The `interactive` parameter prompts new password for the users, whereas `auto` generates them for you.

`elastic` user is the superuser for elastic-cluster.

Read more one configuring security [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-security.html).

Comment: How can I script that (ansible) ? I want to be able to install and set my username and password without any screen interaction.

Comment: It has an auto and an interactive mode, so you should be able to automate it